# SQL Query executed with error in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am not a SQL developer. I am executing below query which is a sub query of a select statement.

The query fail with below error for this specific sub query.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I am having no clue why this is getting error.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN LJT.POSTING IN (20, 31, 41) 
            AND LEFT(LJT.VOUCHER, 3) NOT IN ('REC', 'PAY', 'GEN', 'ARA', 'NET','900','BDJ','004') 
          THEN (SELECT TOP (1) dbo.CUSTTRANS.INVOICE 
                FROM dbo.CUSTTRANS WITH (nolock) 
                WHERE CUSTTRANS.VOUCHER = LJT.voucher 
                  AND CUSTTRANS.DATAAREAID = LJT.DATAAREAID 
                  AND CUSTTRANS.TRANSDATE = LJT.TRANSDATE 
                UNION
                SELECT TOP (1) dbo.VENDTRANS.VOUCHER 
                FROM dbo.VENDTRANS WITH (nolock) 
                WHERE VENDTRANS.VOUCHER = LJT.voucher 
                  AND VENDTRANS.DATAAREAID = LJT.DATAAREAID 
                  AND VENDTRANS.TRANSDATE = LJT.TRANSDATE)
          ELSE LJT.Voucher 
    END AS NumberTransaction5
FROM 
    BEANRSQLDAX.ecu_AX2009_sp1_ru8_prd.dbo.LedgerTRANS LJT WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Also, there are many other sub queries which are exactly like this one but only this is getting error.

Can anyone give me some hint please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Select top (1) union select top (1) returns two rows.  You can't force two rows into the value of column (LJT.Voucher)

Comment: Thank you @RThomas, This is strange, there is same sub query in select statement with different LJT.POSTING values and It is executing fine !!!!

Comment: @Aditya Sawant - It could be executing fine because one of the queries returns no records. You can only assign one value from a query to a value in the where clause. You could concatenate the values together as a comma delimited string or return two fields using the same conditions.

Comment: `SELECT top(1) union select top(1)` will return only one row if both selects return the same value (contrary to `union all`). Perhaps that's the case with the other subquery. Also, a `top(1)` without an `order by` is suspicious.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Can you please help me to avoid this error. I tried using CTE table but guess it is not supported in Subqueries. Do you have any alternative

Comment: @AdityaSawant I don't know what you are trying to do here. So, no, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: And are you really using sql server 2008r2? Time for an upgrade I think

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion - with caveats:

As the error message clearly states your case expression contains a sub-query that is returning more than one row. This is due to the fact that there are a further 2 sub-queries and both are capable of returning a row. Use of `UNION` between those sub-queries does NOT guarantee only a single value is ultimately returned as both values would need to be identical to reduce them to 1 row (but it would probably be extremely rare for an invoice and a voucher to be identical!). So you need to reconsider what happens if both of those sub-queries do return a value. e.g:

- Do you prioritize the Invoice over the Voucher (use `coalesce`)
- Do you concatenate both values?

Below I am suggesting the use of coalesce, but you can alter to concatenate if that's what you decide to do. So, I propose that instead of using correlated sub-queries within a case expression, move both into separate OUTER APPLYs like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN LJT.POSTING IN (20, 31, 41)
            AND LEFT(LJT.VOUCHER, 3) NOT IN ('REC', 'PAY', 'GEN', 'ARA', 'NET', '900', 'BDJ', '004')
            THEN coalesce(oac.cust_invoice, oav.vend_voucher)
        ELSE LJT.Voucher
        END AS NumberTransaction5
FROM BEANRSQLDAX.ecu_AX2009_sp1_ru8_prd.dbo.LedgerTRANS LJT WITH (NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) dbo.CUSTTRANS.INVOICE AS cust_invoice
    FROM dbo.CUSTTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE CUSTTRANS.VOUCHER = LJT.voucher
        AND CUSTTRANS.DATAAREAID = LJT.DATAAREAID
        AND CUSTTRANS.TRANSDATE = LJT.TRANSDATE
        AND LJT.POSTING IN (20, 31, 41)
        AND LEFT(LJT.VOUCHER, 3) NOT IN ('REC', 'PAY', 'GEN', 'ARA', 'NET', '900', 'BDJ', '004')
    ORDER BY CUSTTRANS.TRANSDATE DESC
    ) AS oac
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) dbo.VENDTRANS.VOUCHER AS vend_voucher
    FROM dbo.VENDTRANS WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE VENDTRANS.VOUCHER = LJT.voucher
        AND VENDTRANS.DATAAREAID = LJT.DATAAREAID
        AND VENDTRANS.TRANSDATE = LJT.TRANSDATE
        AND LJT.POSTING IN (20, 31, 41)
        AND LEFT(LJT.VOUCHER, 3) NOT IN ('REC', 'PAY', 'GEN', 'ARA', 'NET', '900', 'BDJ', '004')
    ORDER BY VENDTRANS.TRANSDATE
    ) AS oav
```

Also note that when using `TOP` you should also use `ORDER BY` otherwise the result is indeterminate - but I don't know what columns make sense to order by so I have chosen arbitrarily from the few columns that are identified. You should correct this in the final query.